# How do I find the statistical range of values?

Tags: function, google-sheets, statistics, range

In Google Sheets:

I find the average using `=ROUND(AVERAGE(A1:B2),1)` and
the maximum using `=MAX(A1:B2)` and
the median using `=ROUND(MEDIAN(A1:B2),1)`.

I looked through the list of functions Google provides, but I could not find a way to calculate the statistical range of a range of data cells.

How can I find the statistical range of `A1:B2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
=round(max(A1:B2),1)-round(min(A1:B2),1)
```

Comment: So there's no =RANGE function?

Comment: No. Range has other meanings. I did add round to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find a statistical range function in google sheets.

I solved it with this formula:

=MAX(A5:A300) - MIN(A5:A300)

substitute your range of cells

Comment: This is the same thing as the answer from last year that has already been accepted, this is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=MAP(MAX(A1:B2), MIN(A1:B2), LAMBDA(max, min, max-min))
```

[image]

or:

```
=LAMBDA(x, MAX(x)-MIN(x))(A1:B2)
```

[image]